# CHECK TABLE table_name; when using InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

Assuming an InnoDB table, will the following command ...

```
CHECK TABLE table_name;
```

... cause MySQL to ...

- a.) Check only the data content of the table
- b.) Check only the index content of the table
- c.) Check both the data content and the index content of the table

Comment: CHECK TABLE checks a table or tables for errors. CHECK TABLE works for InnoDB, MyISAM, ARCHIVE, and CSV tables. For MyISAM tables, the key statistics are updated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those options are ignored on innoDb tables. [MySQL CHECK TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/check-table.html).

> The different check options that can be given are shown in the following table. These options are passed to the storage engine, which may use them or not. MyISAM uses them; they are ignored for InnoDB tables.

[This guy](http://shinguz.blogspot.com/2010/01/what-is-check-table-doing-with-innodb.html) took at look at the `CHECK TABLE` code for innoDb and explains it pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The "CHECK TABLE" option has been removed from the question. Do you know the answer? :-)

Comment: @knorv: I wasn't terribly familiar with the process, but I've updated my answer with another resource that explains it nicely.